# Stationary and independent increments in Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t:t\geq0)$ be a standard Brownian motion. I need to solve $\mathbb{P}(B_2-B_1>1|B_{0.5}=2)$. I first thought of using independent increments to get $\mathbb{P}(B_2-B_1>1)$, and then using stationarity this equals $\mathbb{P}(B_1>1)$, which can be solved with the normal cdf. However, if I first use stationarity, I obtain $\mathbb{P}(B_1>1|B_{0.5}=2)$, and then I can't use independence. Is my logic in the first part correct? Or should I approach it differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stationarity doesn't tell you $\mathbb{P}(B_2-B_1>1|B_{0.5}=2)=\mathbb{P}(B_1>1|B_{0.5}=2)$. It only tells you $\mathbb{P}(B_2-B_1>1)=\mathbb{P}(B_1>1)$. Thus your first part is correct, but not your second approach. Think about this (counter)example: Consider $\mathbb{P}(B_{1.5}-B_1>3|B_{0.5}=2)$, if it was equal to $\mathbb{P}(B_{0.5}>3|B_{0.5}=2)$, the probability $\mathbb{P}(B_{1.5}-B_1>3|B_{0.5}=2)$ would be zero, which is definitely not true.

Comment: Thank you! That example is useful